# Some Rest APIs Only Accessible On https While Other Only Accessible On http

Tags: spring, tomcat, ssl, https

I have set up SSL on a Tomcat and made code and configuration changes on its client so that the client can access both http and https ports programatively. Now, how can I configure the application or Tomcat so that some application Rest APIs only are accessible through https while others are only accessible through http? The application is built with Spring. It doesn't use Spring Security. If a Spring Security is in place, some urls can be configured with a secure access and the rest with insecure access.

Comment: Are both the API and the [other stuff] in the same webapp, or are they separate applications?

Comment: They are in the same application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enforce any restrictions you'd like on any URLs by writing a `Filter` and binding it to whatever URL patterns you wish. For this case, you could use a `Filter` like this:

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;

public class SecureFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(!request.isSecure()) {
            // Do whatever you want
            // a. throw an error - e.g. respond with 403
            // b. redirect to HTTPS
            // c. ??
        } else {
            // Allow the request to be processed as usual
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your `WEB-INF/web.xml` file, register the `Filter` and map it to some URL patterns:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>REST-security</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.whatever.SecureFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

....

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>REST-security</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/anything-else/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure reverse proxy (NGINX server) to serve request as per your requirement.

NGINX server need to be place in-front of your tomcat server, then client will 1st call to NGINX server and then depends on request you can configure to pass request to http or https to your tomcat.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Comment: Thanks very much for your input. That definitely is another approach we can consider. I don't know whether it is possible to solve the problem without introducing other servers or not